# Bootstrap struggle with Angular

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to reproduce some bootsrap example that i saw on their website but unsuccessfully

I would like to put an input box next to a second one
It would be like "message box1 box2"

So i first tryied to use grid system to have 3 messsages next to each other in the same raw.
Problem is that it ends up being message1 then message2 on a second raw then message3 on a third raw

Here is the code i used in my html file :

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <h4>Service : Allo</h4>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        1 of 2
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        2 of 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: The "Hello !" at the first line disapeared !

Comment: Instead of html please put stackblitz or plunkr link.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like,

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <h4>Service : Allo</h4>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="w-100">
        1 of 2
      </div>
      <div class="w-100">
        2 of 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It changes nothing for me :(

Comment: check this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSGS6ITCS0QP